# How to map multiple domains to a single service programatically?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, domain, google-cloud-platform

I built a CMS as SaaS. In addition, I build a NextJS app that renders the content, the user created through the CMS. The NextJS app is deployed as Google Cloud Run service. It fetches the data from the CMS and renders the website respectively.

This works fine. However, the users should be able to connect their own domain. This means, unlimited domains need to be mapped to a single Cloud Run service programmatically by the backend.

According to the documentation, this is not possible with Cloud Run alone but I was wondering if there is a workaround to achieve this.

Comment: What documentation? Why do you disbelieve it?

Comment: what is [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Cloud Run [**Official Documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#command-line), it states that in **Cloud Run** , mapping domains is not possible since you need to validate the ownership of the domains:

> "You must [verify domain ownership](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?hl=en) the first time you use that
> domain in the Google Cloud project"

Google Cloud Platform does not offer an API to verify domains.

On the other side, Google Cloud Run does not support unlimited domain names as endpoints. You can review the quotas for Cloud Run and HTTP(S) Load Balancer.

An alternative is to use **Cloud Run for Anthos** and map your customer's domains to the IP of the [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/integrating-https-load-balancing-with-istio-and-cloud-run-for-anthos-deployed-on-gke).